# How to refer to elements of a dynamic array in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, regex

I'm trying to create teaching timetables dynamically, by searching through a large table with all of the information about what time a lesson takes place, who the tutor is, what age group is being taught, and what subject it is.

I'm able to generate all of the information using a combination of `FILTER` and `QUERY`. Below is how I want it to look vs. how it outputs.

[image]

I could use `JOIN` to group all the information in one cell and use the line return delimiter to split them, but then I can't arrange each item in the array how I like. I want to dynamically concatenate the cells so that, for example, I can put multiple fields on one line, and also be able to apply conditional logic based on the results of the `QUERY`. For example, if one column is blank, use an `IF` statement to omit it.

What I need to know is how to create an array based on a query, and then in the same formula line, refer to individual elements within that array. So something like `IF(ThisArray[0]<>"", ThisArray[0] & ThisArray[1])` and so on.

This is the formula I'm currently using:

```
=JOIN(CHAR(10), QUERY(FILTER('Timetable'!$B$2:$R$620, 'Timetable'!$B$2:$B$620=B$3, 'Timetable'!$J$2:$J$620=$A4, 'Timetable'!$H$2:$H$620=$A$3), "SELECT Col13, Col15, Col14, Col5"))
```

Is there a way to do this?

EDIT: I've just discovered the `TEXTJOIN` formula, which is better than my current solution, especially as it allows me to join 2D arrays. So more than one lesson can be stored in the same cell. However, I can't find any way to put an extra line return in between rows to make it more readable, so it just generates like:

```
Philosophy
16-17
John Smith
English Language
13-15
Jane Doe
```

Which is better but not perfect. The ideal scenario is that I can dynamically concatenate each row that's generated by the `FILTER` and `QUERY`, into a single cell, with line returns in between.

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: I can't share the original data, but this is a facsimile which hopefully explains what I'm trying to do https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18jJi4Bo_7Jl8WR2WesMbC1QaL5sXNBAdJ7I5tt7xoZo/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below formula takes the OP query formula and inserts an extra column with value ":" between 3th and 4th column. then the outer QUERY shmushes all columns in one column and appends a unique character ♦ to all values.

Then textjoin joins all data with char(10) >> that's your empty row between sets.

Next a series of regexreplaces are applied to finetune the final output inner one replaces a special character with a new line.

Middle one removes new line if its before "Medicine" and outer one fixes the issue with 2nd row of each set .

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10), 1,
QUERY(TRANSPOSE("♦"&QUERY(FILTER('Source table'!$A$2:$G$6,'Source table'!$A$2:$A$6=$B3),
"select Col2,Col3,':',Col4,Col5,Col6 label ':'''")),,999^99)), "♦",
CHAR(10)), "^"&CHAR(10), ), " "&CHAR(10)&": "&CHAR(10), ": "))
```

[image: 0]